# How to design a relationship between team and game?

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I have come up with two options to relate teams and games in my database; which one is most appropriate?

I was trying to make it simple, here is what I want. `Teams` have many `games`, and each `game` has a `home team` and an `away team`. It's a many to many relationship.

Here is what I thought:

[image]

I am not sure whether I should put a `boolean` field called `ishome` in `competes` table or add two fields called `home_id` and `away_id`, and set them as `foreign` key to references `team.id` like in following picture.

[image]

Comment: Use option 2 you mentioned

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me some advices? Is that because each game has only fixed two teams? If each game has dynamic number of team, should I use option 1?

Comment: Exactly. Use it if you only have a fixed number of teams

Comment: Thanks, I got it. How about you put something as answer? I will pick that as best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have always 2 teams playing against each other you can use

```
competes table
--------------
home_team_id
away_team_id
game_id
```

like in your 2nd option. But if you have a dynamic number of teams in a game then use the other.